# Creating a list of ComboBoxes using VBA that update the values of cells specified in the code

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

What I am trying to do is to create a program that adds combo boxes with some options. These options should then, depending on the option selected, change some values in some cells that I specify in code.

This is how I make the combo lists:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E")
 .ColumnWidth = 25
End With

For i = 1 To 6
    Set curCombo = Sheet1.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(i, 5).Left, Top:=Cells(i, 5).Top, Width:=100, Height:=15)
    With curCombo
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 3
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "Completed", 1
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "In Progress", 2
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "To be done", 3
        .Name = "myCombo" & CStr(i)
        .OnAction = "myCombo_Change"
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

I want each of the dropdown values trigger the event `myCombo_Change` and then simply change the cell "D" For example, combo box 3 is located at E3 and I want the "To be done" to clear the cell D3 and the completed to simply store the date (and time) to the cell D3. This should be done for all combo boxes in the E Column.

```
Private Sub myCombo_Change(index As Integer)

Me.Range("D" & CStr(index)) = Me.myCombo.Value

End Sub
```

This is the code I started thinking about, but I have no idea how to call the event with an integer as the index parameter NOR how to access the cell using said index.

The effect I want is something along the lines of this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application.Caller` to get the name of the control that called the myCombo_Change event.

```
Sub myCombo_Change()

    Dim curCombo As Shape
    Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    curCombo.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1) = Now

End Sub
```

### Assign the myCombo_Change to all existing DropDown:

```
Sub AssignMacroToAllListBoxes()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each sh In ws.Shapes
            If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "DropDown" Then
                sh.OLEFormat.Object.OnAction = "myCombo_Change"
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

### Delete all DropDowns on Sheet1

```
Sub DeleteAllDropDownsOnSheet()
    For Each sh In Sheet1.Shapes
        If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "DropDown" Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd use `ActiveSheet` to make it more _general_, should OP change worksheet name. And `Date` instead of `Now` to be more adherent to its example

Comment: @user3598756 The OP actually want date-time `"the date (and time)"`.  ActiveSheet make a lot of since. I'll update my answer now.  Thanks!!

Comment: "date-time": you're right. I only looked at the screenshot

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didnt know you could use `Application.Caller` for this. However, there is a slight problem. http://puu.sh/r37FJ/e8b4816da8.png I have macros enabled, but the macro does not run. I tried putting it in the sheet and in the workbook objects to no avail.

Comment: Is `myCombo_Change` in a public module?  I was kind of curious why you are adding combo boxes everytime the workbook is opened?

Comment: @ThomasInzina The excel file I have have a LOT of drop down menus all over the place and I was told, with no experience with VBA or excels systems, to make it so that for each ListBox that was already in the document every time someone changed their selection it would update the value next to it. What I wrote down was just my initial attempt. If you have something better, please do tell. I really dont want to change n ListBoxes using code just to keep track of them, but I see no other option.

Comment: The problem is that every time you open the workbook you are stacking new dropdowns on top of each other.  I updated my answer with macros that will help you fix the workbook.  You need to move `Workbook_Open` to a normal module and call it just once after you remove the listboxes on Sheet1.

Comment: You can loop through all items without having their names I see! Thanks. This is a major help. Sometimes I wish people would stop assuming you can program in any language and framework just because we are programmers. ^^ Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Sometimes I wish that I would stop assuming that I can program in any language or on any framework!...lol